# Using jquery, Is it possible to show and hide a div that contains javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have some javascript code that implements a slide show.

I have placed the functions to run the slideshow inside a div like this:

```
<div id="portfolio">

  <script>

    var imgArray = new Array();
    imgArray[0] = "smaller_acorn.jpg";
    imgArray[1] = "slideshow/01.jpg";
    imgArray[2] = "slideshow/02.jpg";
    imgArray[3] = "slideshow/03.jpg";
    imgArray[4] = "slideshow/04.jpg";
    imgArray[5] = "slideshow/05.jpg";
    imgArray[6] = "slideshow/06.jpg";

    slideshowMerge('Slideshow1','',imgArray,20,3000);
  </script>
</div>
```

I want to show/hide this div using a jquery hover function. 
I have already written some working jquery hover functions which change the opacity of other elements.

```
 $("#contact").hover( function () {
     $('#acorn').css({opacity : .1});
     $('#contactblurb').css({opacity: 1.0});
 }, function () 
 {
     $('#acorn').css({opacity : .5});
     $('#contactblurb').css({opacity: 0.0});
 }
 );
```

But show/hide or change opacity doesn't seem to work for this div.

Any ideas?

NB - please see the jsFiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/beeband/qgW9V/12/

Comment: Why does the javascript need to be inside a div?  Also, I suspect the show/hide and opacity is actually working, but the div has no DOM contents so the visual impact is nothing.

Comment: the 2 code parts are totally unrelated to each other, can you please provide a jsfiddle otherwise this is like marvel reading.

Comment: @BrianFlanagan Because I want to give some css style properties to the slideshow, like margin and padding. Perhaps it doesn't need to be though? . . .

Comment: That's  correct.  There's no need to encapsulate the javascript you're applying to a particular node within the node.

Comment: @mightyuhu i added js fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/beeband/qgW9V/12/

Answer (score 0):

[Here's a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brianflanagan/ZkWbH/) to demonstrate.  The JavaScript for the image swap is different from what you're trying to do with the hover trigger.  I'm not sure if you want them to be related in anyway, but you'll still need the hover to function first.

Answer (score 0):

Sure, the trick is to make sure that the `<script>` tag is visible:

```
$("#portfolio > script").css("display","block");​​​​​​​​​​​​​​​
```

Note that `.show()` doesn't work here.